# Why copy to clipboard doesn't work using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm trying this function:

```
function copyToClipboard(str) {

const el = document.createElement('textarea');
el.textContent = str;
el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
el.style.position = 'absolute';
el.style.left = '-9999px';
document.body.appendChild(el);
const selected =
    document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0 ?
    document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) :
    false;
el.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
document.body.removeChild(el);
if (selected) {
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    document.getSelection().addRange(selected);
}
alert("Success");}
```

I've tried with el.value = str; too.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) has been deprecated

Comment: Do you see an error?

Comment: The code runs successfully on my browser though. It could be a matter of `execCommand` not being supported.

Comment: Ohh, it must be that. Not, I don't get any type of error.

Comment: Read through the answers for something different though @EzequiasLopes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `document.execCommand` has been deprecated but still accessible across web browsers

The `navigator.clipboard API` is an alternative [navigator.clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)

You pass in the text to be copied to the clipboard like so

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(str_to_copy).then(success_callback, failure_callback);
```

**Note that the tab must be active for this to work else you won’t have permissions to copy the clipboard**

The API is asynchronous so you can use the `.then` callback to alert the user if copying the clipboard was successful or not. Check out the [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=clipboard%20api) for its availability across web browsers.

Comment: Kudos for mentioning the need for the tab to be active. In my case, I was trying to debug the problem in the console and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way to copy the **text to clipboard**.

```js
 function copyToClipboradFunc() {

      let copiedText = document.getElementById("copyMe");
          copiedText.select();
          copiedText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
    
          document.execCommand("copy");
    
          console.log("Copied the text: " + copiedText.value);
    }
```

```html
 <input type="text" value="Amoos Check Console" id="copyMe">

<button onclick="copyToClipboradFunc()">Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

Minor edits in your code.

```js
/*
YOUR CODE
*/
function copyToClipboard(str) {

const el = document.createElement('textarea');
el.textContent = str;
el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
el.style.position = 'absolute';
el.style.left = '-9999px';
document.body.appendChild(el);
const selected =
    document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0 ?
    document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) :
    false;
el.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
document.body.removeChild(el);
if (selected) {
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    document.getSelection().addRange(selected);
}
alert("Copy Text: " + str );}
```

```html
<!-- YOUR CODE  -->
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('Your Function Copied')">Copy ( Original Function )</button>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why your answer works and the OPs code doesn't work.

Comment: I updated your code too with minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an element that will be appended to DOM for a split second, just to allow the `execCommand("copy")`... And that will "display" at left `-9999px`.

So why the `el.setAttribute('readonly', '');` ?

Just remove it and try again. My guess is the `el.select();` just doesn't work on a `readonly` element.

***Disclaimer***: I did test nothing. But from what I read, this is the only weird thing to mention. Else is to find a duplicate answer or mark it as *unreproducible*.

Comment: Just think... You are spoofing a select on a readonly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some research I found the solution. Thanks to @VLAZ and @a.mola I found out that execCommand is deprecated. So I started to look for alternatives. I found about the clipboard API on this page [Using the Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard), that's from https://developer.mozilla.org/, so we know that's serious business. Anyway, here's my working function:

```js
function copyToClipboard(str) {
    navigator.permissions.query({
        name: "clipboard-write"
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.state == "granted") {
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(str).then(function () {
                alert("Enlace copiado con succeso!");
            }, function () {
                alert("No fue posible copiar el enlace.");
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this. navigator.clipboard doesnt work for http.

```
function CopyToClipBoard(textToCopy) {
var successMessage = 'Success! The text was copied to your clipboard';
var errorMessage = 'Oops! Copy to clipboard failed. ';

// navigator clipboard api needs a secure context (https)
if (navigator.clipboard && window.isSecureContext) {

    // navigator clipboard api method'
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy).then(
        function () {
            /* clipboard successfully set */
            console.log(successMessage)
        },
        function () {
            /* clipboard write failed */
            console.warn(errorMessage)
        }
    )
} else
    if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {

    // text area method
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.value = textarea.textContent = textToCopy;
    textarea.style.opacity = "0"; 

    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.focus();
        textarea.select();

        var selection = document.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        
        range.selectNode(textarea);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

    try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy'); // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
        var msg = successful ? console.log(successMessage) : console.warn(errorMessage);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.warn(errorMessage, ex);
    }
    finally {
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        document.body.removeChild(textarea);
    }
}
```