# JavaScript - Convert p tag to text area and copy changed text to clipboard

Tags: javascript, replace, textarea, clipboard

How to achieve this? In an HTML page, there is a p tag with some content (but only with indentations through &nbsp; and new line tags <br>).
I'd like to offer two buttons: one to convert the p tag into a text area so that the existing content can be adapted by the user, one to copy the content (if the content was not adapted, the original content should be copied, if adapted, certainly the adapted code should be copied).
I have prepared the code below so far. The final functionality should be (most of it not working/implemented in the snippet; the solution should be JS only):

- Click Copy: copies the changed content or original content if not adapted
- Click Adapt: turns the p tag into a text area, user can adapt the text
- The text area should retain the original format: indentations and the line breaks but it should not display the HTML tags (e.g. <br>)
- When the adapted content is copied after clicking Copy, the text area should disappear and the original content should be displayed again (the original p tag, not the text area), i.e. all the changes should be reverted
- When clicking Adapt and then Adapt a second time, also all the changes should be reverted and the original p should be displayed again (otherwise, the text area would not vanish until page reload). Idea: When the Adapt button gets clicked, the name of the button should change to something like "Revert", and after clicking "Revert" the original p and the button "Adapt" could be displayed again.
- How to position the Copy button in the first place and then the Adapt button right next to it? How to then reference to the p tag? It must work without a predefined ID.

Any further ideas? Thanks!

```html
<button onclick="edit(this)">Adapt</button>
<p>some text 1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;some text 2<br>&nbsp;some text 3&nbsp;&nbsp;some text 4 &amp;&amp; .... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;..... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;...... <br>...... <br><br></p>
<button title="Copy to clipboard" onclick="copy_text(this)">Copy</button>

<script>
function edit(item) {
    var a = item.nextElementSibling;  
    a.outerHTML = a.outerHTML.replace(/<p>/g, '<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px ">').replace(/<\/p>/g, '</textarea>'); 
  }
</script>
<script>
    function copy_text(item) {
    const str = item.previousElementSibling.innerText;
    const el = document.createElement("textarea");
    el.value = str;
    el.setAttribute("readonly", "");
    el.style.position = "absolute";
    el.style.left = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(el);
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test it here in [`StackBlitz`](https://jennab.stackblitz.io)

I don't know how you intend finding the `p` element an `id` or a `class` or an  `attribute` but for this answer I just used the tag.

Check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66609051/15350139) for why I used the Clipboard API

[`ReplaceWith MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)

```js
let original = '';
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')];

function edit(button) {
  let paragraph = button.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
  button.innerText = paragraph.tagName == 'P' ? 'Revert' : 'Adapt';

  if (paragraph.tagName == 'P') {
    original = paragraph.innerHTML;
    const textarea = Object.assign(document.createElement('textarea'), {
      innerHTML: paragraph.innerText, // I use the innerText so that the HTML tags will be stripped but the space and new lines will be kept
      style: 'width: 100%; height: 100px;' // Style for the textarea
    });

    paragraph.replaceWith(textarea); // Replace the p tag directly with the new textarea
  } else {
    const p = Object.assign(document.createElement('p'), {
      innerHTML: original
    });
    
    paragraph.replaceWith(p);
  }
}

function copy_text(button) {
  let paragraph = button.nextElementSibling;
  const str = paragraph.value || paragraph.innerText;

  navigator.clipboard.writeText(str).then(_ => {
    if (paragraph.tagName !== 'P') { // To convert the textarea back to the p
      const p = Object.assign(document.createElement('p'), {
        innerHTML: original // Convert the new lines back to br tag and the spaces to &nbsp
      });
      paragraph.replaceWith(p);
    }

    button.previousElementSibling.innerText = 'Adapt';
    alert('Copied');
  }, e => alert(`Failed: ${e}`));
};

// Event Listeners
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const buttonType = button.innerText.toLowerCase();
  if (['adapt', 'revert'].includes(buttonType)) edit(button);
  else if (buttonType == 'copy') copy_text(button);
}));
```

```html
<h1>Paragraph 1</h1>
<button>Adapt</button>
<button title="Copy to clipboard">Copy</button>

<p>some text 1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;some text 2<br>&nbsp;some text 3&nbsp;&nbsp;some text 4 &amp;&amp; .... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;..... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;...... <br>...... <br><br></p>

<h1>Paragraph 2</h1>

<button>Adapt</button>
<button title="Copy to clipboard">Copy</button>

<p>some text 1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;some text 2<br>&nbsp;some text 3&nbsp;&nbsp;some text 4 &amp;&amp; .... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;..... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...... <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;...... <br>...... <br><br></p>
```

Comment: Comes really close. Thanks. 1. No change, just Copy: clipboard text = "undefined". 2. Adpat content,  Copy, fine. But once the Copy button was clicked, the content displayed should also revert to the original code 3. Can the buttons be without Ids? why: same buttons come more than once (several text snippets like this on the pages that should each be adaptable and copyable like this). 4. same code several times on pages: 
document.querySelector('p'); will most probably not work for my purposes. Any chance to achieve it with something like nextElementSibling etc.? 
Can you please support.

Comment: What do you mean by `No change, just Copy: clipboard text = "undefined"`
So under what case will the content change?
Yes we can use `nextElementSibling`. Look at the link I linked

Comment: So when you click the `copy` button, it is meant to copy the text in the box and then revert to the original? or copy the original and still revert to the original

Comment: when I transfer your snippet and run it (with jsfiddle and others I saw it's not possible beacuse of some issue "Failed: NotAllowedError: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document"), and I immediately click Copy without clicking Adapt first (with the assumption that then the original, unadapted code is copied), the content in the clipboard is not the expected one. it just spits out "undefined" as text

Comment: Yeah.. Read my answer... I posted a link to one of my other StackOverflow answer's you'll see why there. Leave an upvote too :D

Comment: yes, when clicking copy, the changed content should be copied (if nothing was changed, the original content should be copied). later I could implement an alert displaying the changed content in the alert pop-up  (saying like you have copied this content...). but once copy was clicked, the orinigal content should be displayed in the html again. this is always leading. background: the "content" is actually a "code snippet". users should be able to adapt the code snippet to their needs and then have it in their clipboard for further steps in their own code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231099/discussion-between-a-mola-and-jennab).

Comment: Just too good, a.mola! Thanks a lot for your kind helpfulness and expertise!

Comment: @jennab check the chat.